# PyCharm code search woes

Tags: python, pycharm

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but I hope it is.

I have been using PyCharm for Python development in the last month and a half and there's an issue that irks me a lot since I've moved from Visual Studio (I had to). I am trying to find stuff in the code and PyCharm for some reason just doesn't give me the same replies I get searching the code on GitHub or Visual Studio.

Now I tried the OS X version of PyCharm and the Red Hat compliant version of it. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, double <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and probably everything under the menus and just can't get the results I get elsewhere.

Am I missing something, should I configure additional stuff?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Or how does it behave exactly? I don't have any problems with the search. Even Ctrl + Shift + F (*Find in Path*/*Project(s)*) works properly.

Comment: I try to find functions or variables and I miss a lot of them that show up in GitHub search for example

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to be more specific. For example, add the link to search in a specific file on GitHub which is different from PyCharm, so other can try to reproduce it. For me, PyCharm searches properly. Also, check if you don't have enabled/disabled some configuration by mistake (e.g. Search in comments only, etc.).

Comment: Do you have case-sensitive searching enabled ("Match Case" in the search bar)?

Comment: Don't know how to explain really, maybe I'll try to make a video or something. It's a really weird behavior and it's the same on my Mac and on my Red Hat which makes me think it's a global issue

Comment: I'll check the case sensitive option, thanks

Comment: @mwormser Python itself **is** case-sensitive, so case-sensitivity in search shouldn't be an issue when searching the code. When I'm looking for an identifier `VarName`, I don't want to find `varname` or `vARnAME`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use Ctrl Shift F instead of double Tab

Comment: What's double tab? Anyway, in your question you're referring to *Find...* (Ctrl + F), not *Find in Path* (Ctrl + Shif + F). So I'm completely confused now, I have no clue what you were doing and what is your question about.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the structure in project view. You can get your function and variable names there.